# StackBlitz displaying errors when using Angular Material

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, stackblitz

It looks like and error is occurring in Stackblitz when using Angular Material because of an update of Material.

This even happens in the [official Material website](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)'s examples.

When clicking on the stack blitz examples you'll see this error:

```
Error in turbo_modules/@angular/material@12.0.3/table/table-module.d.ts (8:22)
    Appears in the NgModule.exports of DemoMaterialModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule, Component, Directive, or Pipe class.
```

This likely means that the dependency (@angular/material/table) which declares MatTableModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc

What's the best way to fix this dependency issue?
Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/angular/eqlverbqply?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: hi flash, you should probably provide the like to your stackblitz :)